# Print pdf job won't work (powellshell scripts) after scheduled user is not logged in

Tags: powershell, pdf, task, scheduler, acrobat

We try to use a powershell scripts to print pdf files from a directory. It works fine if you schedule this scripts as task with option "Run only as user is logged on",  but if you schedule the job as "Run whether user is logged on or not", the print pdf doesn't work at all.  Here is the powershell scripts used to print:

```
$process = Start-Process  -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath $outfile -Verb Print -PassThru -Wait | %{sleep 5; $_} | kill
        if ($process.StandardError)
        {
         log $process.StandardError
        }
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The "Print" in powershell script trigger Arobat Reader to print the pdf.  the scripts is running as scheduled task.  We want to make it work even scheduled user is not logged in.  what need change to make it happen?  use Acrobat.exe?

Comment: Has the user account the task is being run on a default printer?

Comment: Yes, the user scheduled the task do run on a default printer